# ActiveX project in Browzer get Zoom Settings

Tags: browser, zooming, activex, cab

I'm maintaining an existing VB6 application.
It's built as an AcitveX control. The build process builds a CAB file which is then fired into a Browser from an HTM file.

My question is, is there any way to detect the Zoom setting once the Application is loaded in the Browser?

It's not a WebBrowser project so, I can't use that object to query the setting, at least I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

During the ActiveX initialization process you are guaranteed to get a SetClientSite callback, among many others, which will give you an IWebBrowser2 pointer. There may be some timing issues with regards to zoom, but this is a starting point.